# Unix search for substring in files in directory

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I know the `grep -rnw . -e "sometext"` command, but I am wanting to search for a substring such as "tack" in all text files in a directory, that would match "stackover".  In my project I am trying to find where the number 44260 is located but I am pretty sure it in as a parameter for a function, and I can't find it.

Comment: In what way does your `grep` not work?

Comment: Consider `find` command, combined with `grep`

Comment: Just remove the `-w` option if you want to find matches within words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very nondefault formatting for `grep`.  With only one pattern to search for, you don't need to use `-e` at all.  Put the path at the *end* of the query.  This is the same as your problematic query:

```
grep -rnw "sometext" .
```

The `-w` flag matches only full words. It effectively changes your query `sometext` to `\bsometext\b` (where `\b` is a word-break character). As @melpomene noted in the comments, just remove the `-w` and you'll match substrings:

```
grep -rn "sometext" .
```